# Como executar Url.Content via Client?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

No ASP.NET MVC é possível executar o `@Url.Content` nas views e nas controllers.
Esta variável retorna o nível relativo em que o site está.

A minha dúvida é: como executar o `Url.Content` via JavaScript? Tem alguma forma no MVC?

**EDITADO**

Exemplo do `@Url.Content` no C#

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/teste.jpg")" />
```

Resultado por ambientes

```
| DEV | /Content/img/teste.jpg" |
| PRD | /NovoSite/Content/img/teste.jpg" |
```

No meu caso, o ambiente de produção está dentro de uma pasta "NovoSite", com a utilização do  `@Url.Content` eu não preciso me preocupar com isto. 
Porém se eu for fazer alguma coisa com javascript/jquery exemplo

```
$("#element").html('<img src="/Content/img/teste.jpg" />');
```

Só ira funcionar no meu ambiente de Dev, e eu preciso alterar o caminho toda vez que eu faço um deploy

Comment: Tiago, você poderia adicionar um trecho de código mostrando o que você quer fazer? ACHO que entendi, mas quero ter certeza.

Comment: Só pra esclarecer: Você quer saber isto porque vai precisar utilizar este caminho em alguma outra função `javascript`, certo? Pode nos falar mais sobre isso?

Comment: @AndreCalil coloquei o exemplo de código porém em chsarp

Comment: @VitorCanova isto mesmo, adicionei mais detalhes na postagem, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize no lugar de `~` um `.` para indicar que é relativo a posição do HTML.

```
$("#element").html('<img src="./Content/img/teste.jpg" />');
```

Se a sua página estiver em `/NovoSite/` vai ficar: `NovoSite/Content/img/teste.jpg`

Ou simplesmente não coloque a `/` no início, também funcionará como endereço relativo.

Comment: Valeu Gabriel o ponto (.) na frente funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Um prazer ajuda-lo @Tiago

Answer (score 1):

Use o pseudo elemento **text** para que a engine do Razor possa considerar expressões C# dentro do código JavaScript. No seu caso, tente da seguinte forma:

```
<text>
    $("#element").html('<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/teste.jpg")" />');
</text>
```

Comment: Eu posso fazer isto mesmo que a função de javascript estiver dentro de um arquivo .js? Ou seja sem ser direto pela View

Comment: Olha, eu acredito que o código JavaScript neste caso tem que estar na View, por que o Razor só analiza códigos em arquivos *.cshtml, no caso de você estar programando em C# (cshtml = "CSharp HTML").

Comment: Mas você pode também criar uma função dentro de um arquivo *.js referenciado por sua View, e então chamar essa função de dentro da sua view, passando como parâmetro a URL já analisada pelo Razor como o trecho de código que eu mostrei. Algo mais ou menos assim:

// arquivo.js
function definaUrlDaImagem(url) {
$("#element").html('<img src="' + url + '" />');
}

// View.cshtml
<text>
    definaUrlDaImagem(@Url.Content("~/Content/img/teste.jpg");
</text>

Answer (score 0):

Tiago, você já tem algumas boas soluções aí. Vou adicionar uma alternativa que é como eu trabalho.
Geralmente é útil guardar o endereço raiz do seu site em alguma variável. Eu injeto isso no HTML, desta forma:

```
<input type="hidden" id="_urlRoot" value="@Url.Content("~/")" />
```

Se preferir direto em JS:

```
var urlRoot = '@Url.Content("~/")';
```

Para acessar, eu deixo uma função parecida com esta em um arquivo JS comum:

```
    function setURL(path) {
        return $('#_urlRoot').val() + path;
    }
```

E a utilização:

```
$("#element").html('<img src="' + setU('Content/img/teste.jpg') + '" />');
```

Comment: Olá André acabei utilizando a solução do Gabriel, colocando o ponto na frente da barra src="./Content/img/teste.jpg", obrigado pelo resposta